# Can I avoid delivering my personal data publicly when I register a domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, legal, domain-registrar, private-registration

I want to create a website hosted by Altervista.org and to purchase the second level domain with the .com extension 
(as I know, domains purchased on Altervista.org are sold by Banzai Media S.r.L.).

While registering the domain, Altervista asks users to provide their personal data correctly (name, last name, address, phone number...) and all these data will appear on the Whois Record for the website associated.

This worries me, since I'm a private user and I don't hold a company, therefore I don't want that users and companies will be able to know who I am, where I live, which is my phone number... In other terms I want to avoid identity theft, spam and other troubles as long as my website will be more popular.

*- can I **avoid delivering** my **personal data** publicly when I **register a domanin**?*

p.s. I want to put advertising on my website. For I would like to find a solution which guarantees privacy and which does not affect any benefit as well.

Comment: Hiding registrant's details is against the ICANN policy. Why to hide, if you are doing a legal business? If you will hide your details this might affect search engines too. But I guess there are plenty of tools you can use, also I think that GoDaddy offers private domain registration very cheap.

Comment: I saw that in some cases Whois reports that the registration is private, hence personal data are not delivered publicly... 
( it' s ok for my name and the email address, but I don't like the idea that my phone number and other info are visible by anyone on the web... )

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/domainaddon/private-registration.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link, is it legal as well? (I editet my Q since I would like not to affect other benefits while hiding my data)

Comment: Yes using Private domain registration is legal and you won't have any impact on the functionality. It mask your info only for views, ICCAN can still see your real information given in the registration but users and competitors can't I think you should search godaddy or ask them for this.

Comment: Ok...Does this service hide my name and last name as well?

Comment: @knif3r "ICCAN can still see your real information" - No one should be able to see your real information, even ICANN. (Except obviously the "privacy" company and _perhaps_ the domain registrar which might hold payment information.)

Comment: So you are telling me that with private domain even `Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN)` can't see your real data?

Comment: @robertalrp yes it does hide your name and last name as well, check the image on the link I've sent you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can purchase private registration with most, if not all, registrants for a fee that's usually just a few dollars per year. Or you can get a post office box and Google phone number to keep it all a little reclusive. Often, the first year can be hidden for free.

There's nothing illegal about doing that. I question the legality of having to pay for the privacy but I don't know the expenses for the provider behind that either.

Comment: thanks for replying. In any case, even by getting a post office box and Google phone number all the other data remain on the Whois page, isn't it?

Comment: @robertalrp The only thing left would be your name and I don't think you can get around that. Would anyone really care if you faked that? I don't know. Do you want to take the chance?

Comment: You purchase private registration from **registrars** not from **registrants**